# Selecting content of another div using javascript by line number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs (div1 and div2). In the div2, I want to specify the line number of div1 and it should display the relevant content of that line of div1. So far I have created this function and it works when I click on any lines in Div1

```
function getContentOfDiv1() {
 var selection = window.document.selection,range, oldBrowser = true;
 selection = window.getSelection();
 if (!selection) {
  range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  oldBrowser = false;
 }else {
  range = document.selection.createRange();
  selection.modify("move", "backward", "lineboundary");
  selection.modify("extend", "forward", "lineboundary");
   if (oldBrowser) {
    var html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    range.select();
    return html;
   }
   var html = document.createElement("div");
   for (var i = 0, len = selection.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
    html.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
   }
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        return html.innerHTML;
    }
 document.getElementById("div1").onclick = function(e) {
var html = getContentOfDiv1();
document.getElementById("div1Result").innerHTML = html;
```

HTML

```
 <div id="div1Result"></div>
<div id="div1">
  This is line 1 <br>
   This is line 2 <br>
    This is line 3 <br>
  This is line 4 <br>
   This is line 5 <br>
    This is line 6 <br>
 </div>
 <div id="div2">
 Specify Line number of div 1
</div>
```

I am able to get the content of Div1 when I select any line of Dv1. What I want is when I specify the line number from div2, then it should show me the content of Div1. Is there any way?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: without seeing some related HTML it's hard to understand this. But AFAIK there's no concept of line numbers in HTML, even in editable content.

Comment: ok thanks for the update. If you're defining `<br>` as a newline, you just need to get the content as a string, split it by `<br>`, and then fetch the relevant indexes based on the user selection. The logic for that is not so hard. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click events don't carry enough informations to pass the line number (as defined by *`<br>`-separated string*). You should at least use use several `div` to reach your goal.

Here's a small snippet to find the line number via jquery, plain javascript can also be used, but the code is simpler with jquery:

```js
$("#lines").click(evt => {
  $("#lines").find("div").each((index, elt) => {
    if (elt==evt.target) {
      console.log("User has clicked on line "+index);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lines">
  <div>line 0 (click me!)</div>
  <div>line 1 (click me!)</div>
  <div>line 2 (click me!)</div>
  <div>line 3 (click me!)</div>
</div>
```